# Suspend and resume ColdFusion code for server intensive process

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a loop the runs over a couple thousand records and for each record it hits is does some image resizing and manipulation on the server. The process runs well in testing over a small record set but when it moves to the live server I would like to suspend and resume the process after 50 records so the server is not taxed to the point of slow performance or quits altogether.

The code looks like this:

```
<cfloop query="imageRecords">
    <!--create and save images to server - sometimes 3 - 7 images for each record -->
</cfloop>
```

Like I said, I would like to pause after 50 records, then resume where it left off. I looked at `cfschedule` but was unsure of how to work that into this.

I also looked at the [sleep()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6f29.html) function but the documentation talks about using this within `cfthread` tags. Others have posted about using it to simulate long processes.

So, I'm not sure `sleep()` can be safely used in the fashion I need it to.

Server is CF9 and db is MySQL.

Comment: Have you considered spinning off a CFTHREAD?

Comment: @AlEverett Yes, good idea. I was actually thinking about wrapping the whole thing in a thread and pausing it. However, I put the sleep function in the loop and it works. It runs the process (I can see the images created by watching the folder), then sleeps, then picks up again. I'm just not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Sleep works just fine in a single threaded environment. <cfset sleep( 5000 ) /> gives you a 5 second pause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different approach which you could combine with probably any of the other approaches:

```
<cfscript>
th=CreateObject("java","java.lang.Thread");
th.setPriority(th.MIN_PRIORITY);
// Your work here
th.setPriority(th.NORM_PRIORITY);
</cfscript>
```

That ought to set the thread to have lower priority than the other threads which are serving your other requests. In theory, you'll get your work done in the shortest time, but with less affect on your other users. I've not had opportunity to test this yet, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a column called worked in the database that is defaulted to 0 and once the image has been updated set the flag to 1. Then your query can be something like

```
SELECT TOP 50 imagename
FROM images
WHERE worked = 0
```

Then set up a CF scheduled task to run every x minutes

Comment: Additionally it makes sense to have some flag in `application` scope to prevent overlapping the tasks if it takes longer than expected.

Comment: @mrbusche I want to avoid adding any columns to the db. You should be able to pause a process then restart. Thanks for the answer. If all else fails, I will reconsider modifying the db.